# How to limit characters in system.xml for textarea in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, module, system.xml

I want to restrict textarea characters length to 150 characters, My system.xml code is below :

```
...
<orderPlaceMessage translate="label">
    <label>Message for order place: </label>
    <frontend_type>textarea</frontend_type>
    <sort_order>1</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>

    {how to limit character length }

</orderPlaceMessage>
...
```

How to to that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used below jQuery script for limit character length :

```
jQuery("#sms_cnfg_advanced_settings textarea").keypress(function(event){
    var maxLength = 160;
    var length = this.value.length;
    if (length >= maxLength)
     {
        this.value = this.value.substring(0, maxLength);
        alert(maxLength + ' characters allowed, excess characters trimmed');
     }
});

jQuery("#sms_cnfg_advanced_settings textarea").on('keyup',function(){
    jQuery('.charnum').remove();
    var maxLength = 160;
    var length = this.value.length;

     var count=maxLength-length;
     jQuery('<span class="charnum">' +count+' Characters left</span>').insertAfter(jQuery(this));

});
```

Answer (score 8):

Add the following to the `<orderPlaceMessage>` element:

```
<validate>validate-length maximum-length-150</validate>
```

This will add these validation CSS classes used by prototype.js. If you enter a longer value, you will see this generic validation message:

[image: Text length does not satisfy specified text range]

So it is a good idea to add a comment as well to let the user know what this range *is*:

```
<comment>Maximum length: 150 characters</comment>
```

If the limit is important for data integrity, you should also add server side validatation, using a backend model. Digital Pianism already linked a tutorial for this: http://alanstorm.com/magento_system_config_validation

And if you want to know more about the various options in system.xml, there is: http://alanstorm.com/magento_system_configuration_in_depth_tutorial

Answer (score 1):

**Client side validation:**

I reckon you have to use the validate tag and create your own validation routine to limit the number of characters.

Have a look here : http://blog.baobaz.com/en/blog/custom-javascript-form-validators

**Server side validation:**

A bit more code and implies clicking on the save button before validating the data: http://alanstorm.com/magento_system_config_validation